# Parameter to form button macro?

Tags: forms, excel, button, vba

I am trying to pass a parameter from a form button to a macro called "Sub ExcelRangeToPowerPoint(s As String)"

I assign the macro using the following syntax as indicated in an other thread: 'ExcelRangeToPowerPoint("mystring")'

When firing the button, I get an error: impossible to execute macro ''ExcelRangeToPowerPoint("mystring")'' ....

Any idea?

Comment: Try removing the () and just a space like `ExcelRangeToPowerPoint "mystring"`

Comment: I finally managed to get it work selecting Macro in "myworkbook.xlsm" instead of "this workbook". It works with the original syntax 'ExcelRangeToPowerPoint("mystring")'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the form code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Module1.test

End Sub
```

This is the module code

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox UserForm.CommandButton1.Value
End Sub
```